# How to set arraylist data in dynamic textview

Tags: java, android, arraylist

whenever i set `rowTextView.setText(" row value #" + str);` then arraylist last value showing there .
My listdata are **60,65,70,75,80** . only last value showing there .I want all data .How can i achive this ????

```
 int size = al_getAllProductSize.size();

            System.out.println("The size of array is: " + size);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {


            }

            final int N = 5; // total number of textviews to add

            final TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[N]; // create an empty array;

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

            for (String str : al_getAllProductSize)
            {

            rowTextView.setText(" row value #" + str); // i want all value through loop

              }

                ll_textViewObj.addView(rowTextView);

                // save a reference to the textview for later
                myTextViews[i] = rowTextView;
            }
```

Comment: Do you want to add all the ArrayList data into a single textview?

Comment: @Dentor for good approach different textview.5 datas for 5 textview

Comment: @Dentor Single textview possible ??

Comment: you could concat the arrayList values into a string and then set that string value to textView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each string in each textview, you can use something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

    // getting respective string val from list
    rowTextView.setText(" row value #" + al_getAllProductSize.get(i));

    ll_textViewObj.addView(rowTextView);

    // save a reference to the textview for later 
    myTextViews[i] = rowTextView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one . hope it will help you.

```
final int X = 5; // total number of textviews to add
final TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[X]; // create an empty array;

for (int i = 0; i < X; i++) {
         // create a new textview
           final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);

         // set value in textview
          rowTextView.setText("row value #" + i);

        // add the textview to the linearlayout
          ll_textViewObj.addView(rowTextView);

         // save a reference to the textview for later
          myTextViews[i] = rowTextView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int size = al_getAllProductSize.size();
TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
     myTextViews[i] = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
     rowTextView.setText( al_getAllProductSize.get(i));
     ll_textViewObj.addView(myTextViews[i]);
     }
```

Comment: both answer working .but #Shaishav first . i will upvote your answer

Comment: I have low rep. thats why unable to upvote your answer .

Comment: `#al_getAllProductSize.get(i)` .I forgot this